# reference file from javascript. Path fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, path

perhaps this is a dummy question but... I have a file that ask for a image and it works just fine. The problem is when I link the javascript file from other directory. The path to the file goes relative to the current file and not to the javscript file it self. Whats my error there? can't?

Thanks in advance.

Directories:

```
/
--css
--js
    --file.js
--imagenes
    --close.png
index.html
```

If I link the image in file.js and it in index.html I'd have to call

```
    this.img = $('<img>');
    this.img.attr('src', 'imagenes/close.png');
    this.div.append(this.img);
```

If I move the Index.html I can't refer that image again.

Comment: Try `/imagenes/close.png`.  That should always use the server root to locate the image.  This should work as long as you don't use virtual paths.

Comment: The link is always from the execution page, never from the script. The contrary would make harder the use of js libraries, which are frequently used from diverse pages (and sometimes diverse web sites).

Comment: Yeah Thats what I mean, "are frequently used from diverse pages (and sometimes diverse web sites) - dystroy". That's what I am tryng to get. Use the script in diferent places. Thats why I don't use '/imagenes/close.png'